# Use props inside event handler

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, react-props

I'm trying to use props inside an event handler. This is a part of my code

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var grid = new Muuri('.grid', {
      //options...
    });
    grid.on('move', (data) => {
      console.log('ok')
      //can't use this.props here
    );
  }
  render() {...}
  constructor() {...}
}
```

The problem is I am not able to access `this.props` inside the 'move' handler.

Comment: You most likely need to bind `this` from wherever you're calling the function from.

Comment: Even with a .bind(this) after my arrow function the console.log(this) return me undefined

Comment: You're using arrow function, so `this` should refer to same `this` as in `componentDidMount`. Can you provide executable example of your issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can store the reference for `this.props` and refer it inside the event handler.

Or 
Access the required individual properties using destructors and then access those properties inside event handler.

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {

        const {prop1name, prop2Name} = this.props;

        //OR

        const thisProps = this.props;




        var grid = new Muuri('.grid', {
            //options...
        });
        grid.on('move', (data) => {
            console.log('ok')
            //access `this.props` using `thisProps` or access individual properties.
            )}
        render() {}
        constructor() {}
    }
```

Comment: I agree with the first proposed solution of destructuring the props object before defining the grid event.

Comment: If I do that I am able to push data inside an array in this.props ?

Comment: @Phobie `this.props` is readonly.You can not and should not do this.Instead use state lifting

Comment: Thanks so I will use state instead of props. The problem is still the same, I can't use state in my event handler and copy the state inside a const will not allow me to push datas and then use them later. By the way, this is a grid with widgets on dashboard and when the user move a widget, I need to keep the index of the widget moved, and send it to a REST API in order to save widgets configuration of the user.